# Github not showing map after uploading a trusted notebook (ipynb)?

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I made my notebook to Trusted in Jupyter Lab, then downloaded it as an .ipynb file and then tried to upload it to github but Github again shows the error

Make this Notebook Trusted to load map: File -> Trust Notebook

How do i make this notebook "Trusted"? vI have already done the trusted part in Jupyter Lab.

[image: I made this trusted]

[image: Downloaded the ipynb]

[image: Uploaded to Github]

[image: Same file rendering in Github]

[image: Error showing again in the map]

Comment: Same problem here. I solved it installing in a conda env, though I do not know why it works via conda and not outside, and do not know how to auth programmatically, without touching buttons around.